# disable touchpad through xinput

Tags: xorg, touchpad, xinput

I am trying to disable touchpad through xinput. But I cannot find the id for my touchpad... Here is xinput list:

```
Virtual core pointer id=2 [master pointer (3)]
⎜ ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer id=4 [slave pointer (2)]
⎜ ↳ DLL07A9:01 044E:120B id=14 [slave pointer (2)]
⎜ ↳ GTech MI wireless mouse Mouse id=11 [slave pointer (2)]
⎜ ↳ GTech MI wireless mouse Consumer Control id=13 [slave pointer (2)]
⎜ ↳ DualPoint Stick id=15 [slave pointer (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard id=3 [master keyboard (2)]
↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard id=5 [slave keyboard (3)]
↳ Power Button id=6 [slave keyboard (3)]
↳ Video Bus id=7 [slave keyboard (3)]
↳ Power Button id=8 [slave keyboard (3)]
↳ Sleep Button id=9 [slave keyboard (3)]
↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD: Integrate id=10 [slave keyboard (3)]
↳ Intel HID events id=16 [slave keyboard (3)]
↳ Intel HID 5 button array id=17 [slave keyboard (3)]
↳ Dell WMI hotkeys id=18 [slave keyboard (3)]
↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard id=19 [slave keyboard (3)]
↳ GTech MI wireless mouse System Control id=12 [slave keyboard (3)]
↳ GTech MI wireless mouse Consumer Control id=20 [slave keyboard (3)]
```

I am using dell precision 3520. Can someone tell me what id corresponds to my touchpad and how you know?

Comment: I suggest trying each one and seeing if it works. My guess is that it's 14, though, simply because I doubt it's the other ones.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively You could download the **"GnomeTweakTool"** and deactivate it under Mouse & Keyboard > Click Emulation

Answer (score 1):

The touchpad your laptop uses is the long sequence (DLL07A9 ...) under master pointer, and has `id=14`. You can verify it is on this page https://certification.ubuntu.com/catalog/component/input:DLL07A9:01044E:120B.

To disable:

`xinput set-prop 14 "Device Enabled" 0`