How do I disable TouchGuard/DisableTouchpadWhileTyping on my Dell laptop touchpad?
I can't find how to disable TouchGuard/DisableTouchpadWhileTyping on my Dell laptop.
I'm using Ubuntu 23.10.

Is this any use? https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000150104/precision-xps-ubuntu-general-touchpad-mouse-issue-fix

I found out how to disable TouchGuard/DisableTouchpadWhileTyping. (This only works fo Ubuntu on Xorg)

Press Crtl+Alt+T
Enter xinput list
Find the ID of the touchpad, it will probably have "touchpad" in its name
Enter xinput set-prop <touchpad-id> "libinput Disable While Typing Enabled" 0
Replace <touchpad-id> with the ID of your touchpad device
Open Startup Applications
Add xinput set-prop <touchpad-id> "libinput Disable While Typing Enabled" 0 as a startup application


Well done. In general, please do add more details in your questions e.g. which model notebook you are using. Also check if your question has been asked and answered already e.g. here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1134222/disable-touchpad-through-xinput
